# How to find which way did mousewheel / touchmove event go in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I disabled scrolling on my project with `overflow:hidden;` in css and intend to use animations when scroll / touchmove event is fired.

I've managed to catch the event with

```
$(document).on('mousewheel touchmove', function());
```

But i can't get the info which direction did the mousewheel or touchmove go. Is there another aproach to this or should i ditch this aproach and go with something different?

My plan was to use tweenmax animations that bind on scroll / touchmove / keyboard arrow keys. And keep the website static aka disable scroll.

Comment: Check the answers here. It worked for me.
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278087/determine-vertical-direction-of-a-touchmove>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this, and gonna try using it and then report on this answer.
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
Plugin is great on desktop but doesn't work on touchmove will have to alter the plugin i guess.

Now to find out how to catch touchmove direction is my only problem, onto finding the solution. So i could manualy trigger the plugin functions as it's missing the touch support even though in manual says it's supported. (reported to the plugin coder)

Found answer in this question [Determine vertical direction of a touchmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278087/determine-vertical-direction-of-a-touchmove)